# How to update a single field of all documents in firestore using flutter?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document

I have a 100 user documents in database, and I have to update one field to 0 in all documents. How do we do it?

Answer (score 8):

As [@Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63321904/6618622) mentioned there's no direct way, you'll have to query the data, get the `DocumentReference` from `QueryDocumentSnapshot` and invoke `update` on it.

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
var querySnapshots = await collection.get();
for (var doc in querySnapshots.docs) {
  await doc.reference.update({
    'single_field': 'newValue',
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Firestore doesn't offer a SQL-like "update where" command that updates everything at once, so you will have to:

1. Query for the documents to update
2. Iterate each [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) and get its DocumentReference object using the [reference property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/reference.html)
3. For each document, [update](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/updateData.html) the field with its new value

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following

1. Query the documents to update
2. Go through each `DocumentSnapshot` and get its `DocumentReference` object using the reference property and for each document, update the field with its new value

```
    void updateNotificationCount() async {
        FirebaseUser _currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        String authid = _currentUser.uid;
        var snapshots =
            activityFeedRef.document(authid).collection('feedItems').snapshots();
        try {
          await snapshots.forEach((snapshot) async {
            List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.documents;
    
            for (var document in documents) {
              await document.reference.updateData(<String, dynamic>{
                'seen': true,
              });
            }
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
        }
      }
```

The code above simply updates all unread notification from false to true immediately the user clicks on the notification tray